# What is the difference between Asset Library and should this library be an asset library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, asset-library

There is always the need to store files there are not documents or videos or audios inside sites' libraries. Ideally we would like to store everything in SharePoint and nothing in the the soon-to-be decommissioned shared drives

I would like to know if somebody can explain if there is a factual difference between the standard asset library (the one with the icon of the "movie") vs taking any document library, removing versioning and saying yes to the setting in advanced settings "do you want this library to be an asset library?"

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint's built-in asset library app is pre-configured to help you manage rich media assets, such as image, audio, and video files.

In the document library advanced settings, set "Should this document library be a site assets library?" as Yes, it actually does not change anything.